# SceneKit change `.allowCameraControl` without refreshing

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit

I'm making a test program that allows the user to switch .allowCameraControl on and off with a button
So I'm using observable objects that update the scene object whenever a variable changes. But every time the .allowCameraControl option is changed, the scene refreshes and objects goes back to its original orientation.
How do I make it so that the object stays in its current orientation even when the .allowCameraControl changes

Here's a minimum reproducible example
ContentView.swift:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

final class Lmao: ObservableObject {
    @Published var yo: SceneView.Options = [.allowsCameraControl]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var l: Lmao
    var scene = SCNScene(named: "myScene.scn")
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SceneView(scene: scene, options: l.yo)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width , 
                      height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2)
            
            Button("allow/disable camera controll") {
                if l.yo == [] {
                    l.yo = [SceneView.Options.allowsCameraControl]
                }
                else {
                    l.yo = []
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func updateLocation(_ location: CGPoint) {
        print(location)
    }
}
```

CameraTestApp.swift:

```swift
@main
struct CameraTestApp: App {
    @StateObject private var ll = Lmao()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(ll)
        }
    }
}
```

myScene.scn: put some random stuff in a scene file

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: ok I just improved it; thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Common approach

In ContentView use @State property wrapper `allowOrNot` for toggling states:

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct ContentView : View {
    
    @State private var text: String = "CamControl is On"
    @State private var allowOrNot: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VRViewContainer(allowOrNot: $allowOrNot)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Text(text)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        allowOrNot.toggle()                            
                        if !allowOrNot { text = "CamControl is OFF" } 
                        else { text = "CamControl is On" }
                    }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In VRViewContainer use @Binding property wrapper.

```
struct VRViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var allowOrNot: Bool
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {
        let sceneView = SCNView(frame: .zero)
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")
        sceneView.scene = scene
        return sceneView            
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: SCNView, context: Context) {
        uiView.allowsCameraControl = allowOrNot
    }
}
```

### Your approach

If you wanna control a camera's transform using your code, you have to retrieve all the sixteen values ​​from the transform matrix (position, orientation and scale) of the scene's default camera node (or from transform of any other SCNCamera node). In both cases, you'll need the `sceneView` instance.

```
sceneView.pointOfView?.transform   // SCNMatrix4
```

In simplified SwiftUI's `SceneView` init you've got the parameter called `pointOfView`:

```
SceneView(scene: SCNScene?, pointOfView: SCNNode?, options: SceneView.Options)
```